# NicEdit detect when toolbar setting has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, nicedit

How to detect if some toolbar settings have been applied  on [**NicEdit**](http://nicedit.com/demos.php) editor (like ***`font size`***, ***`font family`***, etc.)? I'm trying to show a real-time changes, not when the user has lost `focus` or has clicked outside the editor.

```js
$.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/NicEdit/0.93/nicEdit.min.js", function ( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    var _content = "";
    var slideContent = new nicEditor({
        iconsPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/nicedit/0.9r24/nicEditorIcons.gif'
    }).panelInstance('slide_content');
    
    // fix width
    $('.nicEdit-panelContain').parents('div:first').css('width', '100%');
    $('.nicEdit-main').css('width', '100%').css('minHeight', '54px').parents('div:first').css('width', '100%').css('minHeight', '54px');

    $("div.nicEdit-main").bind('keyup', function () {
        _content = $(this).html();
        setOutput(_content);
    });

    slideContent.addEvent('blur', function () {
        _content = $("div.nicEdit-main").html();
        setOutput(_content);
    });

    slideContent.addEvent("focus", function () {
        _content = $("div.nicEdit-main").html();
        setOutput(_content);
    });
    
});

function setOutput(content) {
   $("#output").html(content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
   <label>Content:</label>
   <textarea id="slide_content" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
<br>
Test output: <br><br>
<div id="output"></div>
```